# Why getjson return only 1 row

Tags: json, jquery

I would like to cycle in a list html json file content.

my target is put inside a list html content of test field

```
<ul>
<li>text 1 text 1</li>
<li>text 2 text 2</li>
<li>text 3 text 3</li>
<li>text 4 text 4</li>
</ul>
```

this is my json file (result.js)

```
{
    "news": [
        {
            "title": "text 1 text 1",
            "id": "1111"
        },
        {
            "title": "text 2 text 2",
            "id": "2222"
        },
        {
            "title": "text 3 text 3",
            "id": "3333"
        },
        {
            "title": "text 4 text 4",
            "id": "4444"
        }
    ]

}
```

this is my code htnl with function getjson

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){



$.ajax({     
    url: 'result.js',     
    dataType: 'json',     
    async: false,
    success: processJSON() 
}); 


function processJSON() {

    $.getJSON("result.js",function(result){

      $.each(result, function(i,val){
        HOW CAN CYCLE HERE title field?????????
      });
    });
}


});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="box"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your json seems to be malformed. (missing `{` )

Comment: Please read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) to learn how to access JavaScript objects and arrays. These are the very basics.

Comment: Why does your `$.ajax` have `processJSON` which calls `$.getJSON` as a callback?  P.S. You probably want `success: processJSON` instead of `success: processJSON()`.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter is the current value, so you can access it like so:

```
$.getJSON("result.js",function(result)
{
   $.each(result.news, function(i,val)
   {
      alert(val.title);
   });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

As Rocket pointed out in the comments, you don't need both $.ajax and $.getJSON. Your entire javascript snippet could become the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $.getJSON("result.js",function(result)
    {
       $.each(result.news, function(i,val)
       {
          alert(val.title);
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think `this` actually  refers to the array in `result.news` (`val` too). You have to iterate over the array, not the outer object.

Comment: I think you're right. I updated my answer, the current item is the second parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$.each(result.news` ?

Comment: $.each(result.news Works finally

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but hopefully you get the idea. The key points are:

- You're version calls the ajax endpoint twice
- You don't need the function and everything to be wrapped in the document.ready, just the initial ajax call
- You need to pass the resulting json to the success function
- You need to loop through the news property
- You access properties with either object.property or object['property']

  ```
  function processJSON(data) {
        var list = $('<ul />');
        $.each(data.news, function(i,val){
          list.append($('<li />').append(val.title));
        });
        $('#box').append(list);
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({     
      url: 'result.js',     
      dataType: 'json',     
      async: false,
      success: processJSON 
  }); 
  });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>


  <div id="box"></div>

  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: `processJSON` can be in the `document.ready` so that it's not a global function.

Comment: true enough. I didn't say it couldn't be, just said it didn't have to. Original poster seemed confused about the relationship between functions (I'm basing that on 2 ajax calls to the same endpoint), that I was attempting to make the example as simple as possible. In a complex page, I would agree it's good to avoid global namespace.

Comment: Your `processJSON` has a few issues.  `$('ul')` will select *all* `<ul>` elements on the page.  You want `$('<ul></ul>')` (or `$('<ul/>')`), which makes a new element.  Also, `list` is already a jQuery object, no need to do `$(list)`.

Comment: @Massimo, try success: processJSON(data)

Answer (score 1):

First off, why are you requesting `result.js` twice?  You have a `$.ajax` call whose callback does `$.getJSON`, there's no reason to get the data twice.

Second, you need to loop through result.news, to get each item.

Third, when using functions as variables, lose the `()`.  That will call the function and use its return value, not the function itself.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'result.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: processJSON
});

function processJSON(result){
    $.each(result.news, function(i, val){
        console.log(val.title); // Each news title
    });
}
```

Or using $.getJSON

```
$.getJSON("result.js", processJSON);

function processJSON(result){
    $.each(result.news, function(i, val){
        console.log(val.title); // Each news title
    });
}
```

P.S. Don't use `async: false` unless you *really* need to.  It will lock up the browser until the request is complete.